# Getting undefined when passing php array to javascript array variable through json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am passing an array of string from the file `indexOnLoad.php`. After getting this with the help `XMLHttpRequest()` in JavaScript when I return this array I get the variable as `'undefined'`.

The HTML code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="NavBar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS.css">
    <script src="indexJS.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arrayString;
    </script>
    <title>Find your Bus</title>
</head>`enter code here`

<body bgcolor=#81D4FA onkeypress="test();" onload="arrayString = indexOnLoad();console.log('arrayString ');console.log(arrayString);">
    <ul class="NavBar">
        <li class="NavBarList" id="Home">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                Home
            </a>
            <div class="NavBarListContent" id="homeContent">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Developers</a>
                <a href="#">Suggestions Box</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <li class="NavBarList">
                Administrator
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="filler1">

    </div>
    <div class="SearchBox">
        <input type="text" id="textBoxSearchQuery" placeholder="Search for Anywhere..." list="suggestions"><datalist id="suggestions">
            <option value="Manan">Manan</option>
            <option value="Anant">Anant</option>
        </datalist><img src="search-89.png" name="buttonSearch" value="Search" id="buttonSearch">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please take a look on the body tag and the script containing main problem code.
JavaScript file, which is named as `"indexJS.js"` is:

```
        function indexOnLoad() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            return obj;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "indexOnLoad.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The PHP file, which is named as "indexOnLoad.php" is:

```
<?php

$array = array("1","2","3");

$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
?>
```

the results after this in browser

[image]

Comment: `var arrayString =""; window.onload=function() {    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            arrayString = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(arrayString); /* process here */
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "indexOnLoad.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}} `

Comment: the problem is when I access arrayString variable outside of the responseText block i always get undefined

Comment: Read the duplicate. The A in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous" which means the value is available AFTER the successful return from the call and nowhere else. Put the call to the processing inside the onreadystatechange  function

Comment: Thanks... for all the efforts